# WooCommerce function breaks when declaring second array result

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In my WooCommerce project, in the functions.php file I have written the following function which runs when the WooCommerce shop page loads all products. I have found the source of the problem but can not figure out why it happens.

Somehow only one can exist between: `$prodVars`, `$prodVar` or `$prodPrices`. If all three are active (uncommented) then the shop page loop breaks and shows the first item only. If I comment two of those variables the loop runs perfectly and displays all information.

Is there something that I misunderstood and used incorrectly?

```
function get_desc(){
    $prodID = get_the_ID();
    $product = wc_get_product($prodID);
    $product2 = wc_get_product($prodID);
    $prodDesc = $product->get_short_description();
    echo "<div class='prodDetWrap'>";
    echo "<div class='prodVariations'>";

    $prodVars = $product->get_attributes();

    $prodVar = $product->get_variation_attributes();

    $prodPrices = $product2->get_variation_prices();

        $prodPrice = $prodPrices['price'];
    $prod1Price = current($prodPrice);
    $prodCnt = 0;

    echo "</div>";
    if($prodDesc !== "NULL"){
        echo "<p>";
        echo $prodDesc;
        echo "</p>";
    }else{
        ;
    }

    echo "<p class='disclaimer'>Er varen ikke på lager, bestiller vi dem hjem til jer.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'get_desc', 12);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code, like:

- You are getting 2 times the `WC_Product` object using `wc_get_product()`. Instead you should call the available global `WC_Product` object.
- Segmentation between variable products and other product types is mandatory, as `WC_Variable_Product` methods will throw errors on other product types, like for:

  - `get_variation_attributes()` method,
  - `get_variation_prices()` method,
- `$prodDesc` variable should be defined and `$prodCnt` is not used.
- `else{ ; }` will throw an error.

You should enabled the debug when testing code, using `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in the root `wp-config.php` file of your installation.

Try the following instead:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'get_desc', 12 );

function get_desc(){
    global $product;

    if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    }

    $short_description = $product->get_short_description();

    echo "<div class='prodDetWrap'>
    <div class='prodVariations'>";

    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    // Only WC_Variable_Product methods (for variable products only)
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $variation_attr   = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $variation_prices = $product->get_variation_prices();

        $variation_price  = reset($variation_prices['price']);
    }

    $prodCnt = 0;

    echo "</div>";

    if ( isset($prodDesc) && $prodDesc !== "NULL") {
        echo "<p>";
        echo $prodDesc;
        echo "</p>";
    } else {
        echo '';
    }

    echo "<p class='disclaimer'>Er varen ikke på lager, bestiller vi dem hjem til jer.</p>
    </div>";
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: How about explaining what the mistakes _are_ so users don't have to dissect your code?